# how to plot value counts with showing titles of values in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, categorical-data

I have a df with column 'address-birth'. Addresses are categories.

```
sns.countplot(df_defaulted['birn_addr_area'].value_counts())
```

[image: kk]

But i need addresses appear vertically under each bar. how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
df_defaulted = pd.DataFrame({'birn_addr_area':np.random.choice(['A','B','C','D','E','F','H','K','P'],100)})
sns.countplot(x='birn_addr_area',data=df_defaulted)
```

[image]

You can plot them sorted by counts:

```
sns.countplot(x='birn_addr_area',data=df_defaulted,
               order = df_defaulted['birn_addr_area'].value_counts().index)
```

[image]

Or if you don't need the colors, just do:

```
df_defaulted['birn_addr_area'].value_counts().plot(kind="bar")
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `set_xticklabels`, like that:

```
chart = sns.countplot( <your stuff here> )
chart.set_xticklabels(chart.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45)
```

(you can put any number other than 45)